# Can someone explain my how this exceptions works?

Tags: php, exception

I found an really interesting problem on the internet about Exceptions & Errors, but I can't get it.

```
class MyException extends Exception {
    public function __construct(string $message) {
        $this -> message = $message;
    }
}

class A {
    public function __construct() {
        throw new MyException("an error appeared");
    }
}

$err = null;
try {
    new A();
}
catch (MyException $err) {
    throw new Exception('another error appeared');
}
catch (Exception $err) {
    echo $err;
}
```

When I execute the code I receive

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: another error appeared in C:\xampp
```

I don't understand if it's a problem about the code or this is how it works actually. Maybe you can help me.
That fatal error is for an untreated exception?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second `catch` block does not catch the exception thrown in the first `catch` block. It can only be used to catch a an additional type of exception thrown in the first `try` block.
To catch your second exception you need to add a nested try catch:

```
try {
    new A();
}
catch (MyException $err) {
    try {
        throw new Exception('another error appeared');
    }
    catch (Exception $err) {
        echo $err;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand now!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the fatal error is for an unhandled exception here:

```
$err = null;
try {
    new A();
}
catch (MyException $err) {
--->throw new Exception('another error appeared');
}
catch (Exception $err) {
    echo $err;
}
```

In case you are wondering what is leading to this, it is this line in your code snippet:

```
$err = null;
try {
--->    new A();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @LeWildKitten as sharky rightly mentioned in his response, catch blocks only catch exceptions in the try block that they follow.  
For any reason, if you wish to catch all exceptions in a single catch block, you can remove the additional catch blocks. However, this should only be done if different exceptions need to be handled in a similar way.

Comment: I have a question. Can you tell me what's wrong with that "new A()"?

Comment: @LeWildKitten  If you are wondering why it throws the exception, it is because of the throw statement present in the `__construct` method of the `A` class.